# error in this java program?

Tags: java, generics, error-handling

I am trying to create a generic class for linked list in java and I am facing some errors which I am not able to debug.

Code:

```
class node<T>
{
    T value;
    node<T> next;
}
class LinkedList<T>
{
    static node<T> head,last;
    static int no;
    node<T> current=new node<T>();

    public <T> void add(T x)
    {
        this.current.value=x;
        this.current.next=null;
        last.next=this.current;
        last=this.current;
        if(no==0)
            head=this.current;
        no++;
    }
    public <T> T remove()
    {

        node<T> y=head;
        while(y.next.next!=null)
        {
            y=y.next;
        }
        T z =y.next.value;
        y.next=null;
        last=y;
        return z;   
    }

}
```

I don't have much experience with generics. This is the error I am getting:

```
linkedlist.java:14: error: incompatible types
        this.current.value=x;
                           ^
  required: T#2
  found:    T#1
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>add(T#1)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class LinkedList
linkedlist.java:25: error: incompatible types
        node<T> y=head;
                  ^
  required: node<T#2>
  found:    node<T#1>
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class LinkedList
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>remove()
linkedlist.java:32: error: incompatible types
        last=y;
             ^
  required: node<T#2>
  found:    node<T#1>
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>remove()
    T#2 extends Object declared in class LinkedList
3 errors
```

I know the error is due to the fact that T can be of different types in this cases but I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete `<T>` from the declaration of your `add` and `remove` method because by writing something like

```
public <T> void add (T x)
```

you are saving that variable x can be of any type T and that fine but the problem comes when you are trying to make the assignment inside this method

```
this.current.value=x;
```

You have incompatible type , the type of `current` is different then type of `x`, Why? because `T` used in declaration of `current` is different from `T` used in declaration of `x` that's why you get the error. Delete `<T>` and it should work

like this

```
  public  void add(T x)
    {
        this.current.value=x;
        this.current.next=null;
        last.next=this.current;
        last=this.current;
        if(no==0)
            head=this.current;
        no++;
    }
    public  T remove()
    {

        node<T> y=head;
        while(y.next.next!=null)
        {
            y=y.next;
        }
        T z =y.next.value;
        y.next=null;
        last=y;
        return z;   
    }
```

Also in the declaration of static variables

```
static node<T> head,last;
```

you have compilarion error because **LinkedList.this cannot be referenced from static context**

Comment: Thanks!!That solved my error But I don't understand the reason .I thought that we need to wirte <T> before genric methods.